# Is lxml buggy in handling of attributes as dictionaries via attrib?

Tags: lxml

I am trying to migrate some code from using ElementTree to using lxml.etree and have encountered an error early on:

```
>>> import lxml.etree as ET
>>> main = ET.Element("main")
>>> another = ET.Element("another", foo="bar")
>>> main.attrib.update(another.attrib)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    main.attrib.update(another.attrib)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2153, in lxml.etree._Attrib.update 
    (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:46972)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

But I am able to update using the following:

```
>>> main.attrib.update({'foo': 'bar'})
```

Is this a bug in lxml (version 2.3) or am I just missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm getting the same error, don't think that it's only 2.3 issue.

Workaround:

```
main.attrib.update(dict(another.attrib))

# or more efficient if it has many attributes:
main.attrib.update(another.attrib.iteritems())
```

**UPDATE**

`lxml.etree._Attrib.update` accepts dict or iterable [(source)](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx#L2187). Although `_Attrib` has `dict` interface, it is not `dict` instance.

```
In [3]: type(another.attrib)
Out[3]: lxml.etree._Attrib

In [4]: isinstance(another.attrib, dict)
Out[4]: False
```

So `update` tries to iterate items as `key, value`. Maybe it's done for perfomance. Only `lxml` author knows.

Ways to change it in `lxml`:

1. Subclass `dict`.
2. Check for `hasattr(sequence_or_dict, 'items')`.

I'm not familiar with `Cython` and don't know what is better.

Comment: So, perhaps another.attrib isn't really a dictionary and so you need to force it into one for this idiom to work? (Strange, though, because ElementTree handles it fine)

Comment: @bryn, you are right, see updates in answer. Can you add [issue on github](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/issues)?

Comment: Done. Seems like the type of thing that others would have encountered before me though, especially given how many people rave about lxml on this site.

Comment: I didn't see this problem on my desktop linux distro, but noticed it as soon as I ported to a raspberry pi.  Inserting the call to iteritems() made it work everywhere.